# Simplifying a foreach and Any() with only Linq

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I'd like to rewrite this code to only use Linq:

```
foreach (string dog in dogs)
{
    Assert.That(GetOwnersForDog(dog).Any(x => x.Name == "Me"));
}
```

It shall tell whether all the dogs has at least one owner called "Me".
Any idea?

Comment: what you want to remove ? foreach ?

Comment: Which unit testing framework are you using? Does it have assertions for collections? xUnit has an `Assert.All`, NUnit has [Collection constraints](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Constraints#collection-constraints)

Comment: I'm using Nunit.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think adding LINQ "simplifies" anything, but:

```
Assert.That(dogs.All(dog => GetOwnersForDog(dog).Any(x => x.Name == "Me")));
```

Personally, I preferred the original code.

Comment: Thank you! I did not have any problem with the original, I was just curious how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted primarily for the two natural language statements.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a relationship between `Dog` and `Owner`

```
public class Dog
{
    public List<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**You can do the following**

Check if [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) dog has specified `Owner`

```
var found = Dogs.All(dog => dog.Owners.Any(owner => owner.Name = "Me")):
```

Or check if [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) dogs has specified `Owner`

```
var found = Dogs.Any(dog  => dog.Owners.Any(owner => owner.Name = "Me")):
```

Or if you want to get a list of dogs with specified `Owner` using [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var dogs = Dogs.Where(dog  => dog.Owners.Any(owner => owner.Name = "Me")):
```

Comment: Thanks! Great solutions.